# Expo React Native - Touchable opacity not working on specific iOS device

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, directus

Very strange bug here..

I have an Expo React Native app for processing orders. The other day, one user reported that when pressing on "ORDER NOW" (at the end of the purchase process), the button is unresponsive. The button highlights on touch as expected, but nothing happens, no feedback, no logs in the server, nothing. Just a flashing of the touchable opacity button.

However, if some information is missing an alert will pop up (meaning that the onPress is working fine).

I tried updating, restarting the device, re-installing the app, logging out and in, trying different accounts, etc. but nothing works.

We used two iPhones from different models (13 and 11) from this client and they both behaved the same way. The only thing in common I can find is that they're both logged in with the same iCloud account. Could it be that the iCloud settings for this account are restricting something?

Any ideas on what this could be? Don't know where to start really.

The PURCHASE NOW button:

```
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={formikprops.handleSubmit}
                                style={[{ marginTop: 45 }, shadow.standard]}>
                                <View style={{
                                    backgroundColor: foodhiRed,
                                    justifyContent: "center",
                                    height: 50,
                                    alignSelf: "center",
                                    alignItems: "center",
                                    width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.8,
                                    borderRadius: 6,
                                }}>
                                    <Text style={[cartStyle.cartFloatingBarText, { fontSize: 16 }]}>
                                        {loading ? <Loading /> : "Jetzt bestellen"}
                                    </Text>
                                </View>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
```

THE FORMIK HANDLE SUBMIT

```
  <Formik
                    initialValues={{
                        address: shipping_address && `${shipping_address.street_1}, ${shipping_address.city}, ${shipping_address.postcode}`,
                        deliveryDate: selectedDate,
                        deliveryTime: selectedTime,
                        immediateDelivery,
                        moreDetails: deliveryMessage
                    }}
                    onSubmit={(values) => {
                        if (selectedDate) {
                            if (shipping_address) {
                                handleCallback(values)
                            } else Alert.alert("Alert", "Please provide an address")
                        } else Alert.alert("Alert", "Please specify a date")
                    }}
```

THEN HANDLE CALLBACK THEN SENDS THE "values" TO THE PARENT COMPONENT (check the handleCallback() function at the bottom of the following code:

```
const confirmSubmit = (values) => {
        // IF CONDITION IS MET, AND ORDER IS WITHIN TIME CUTOFF
        dispatch(loadingStart());
        // CHECK IF THERE'S AN ADDRESS REGISTERED
        if (!userProfile.fk_shipping_address) {
            Alert.alert("Addresse", "You must specify an address");
            dispatch(loadingStop());
        } else {
            const orderData = {
                delivery_date: values.deliveryDate,
                total: (values.immediateDelivery ? subTotal : subTotal + farmer.delivery_fee).toFixed(3),
                delivery_fee: values.immediateDelivery ? 0 : farmer.delivery_fee,
                delivery_note: values.moreDetails,
                immediate_order: values.immediateDelivery,
                restaurant: {
                    id: userProfile.id,
                },
                farmer: {
                    id: route.params.farmer.id,
                },
                fk_order_items: cartProducts.map((product) => {
                    const subtotal = (product.item.price - (product.item.price * (product.discount / 100)));
                    const item_total = (product.item.price - (product.item.price * (product.discount / 100))) * product.quantity;

                    return (
                        {
                            product_id: product.item.id,
                            stock_quantity: product.item.stock_quantity,
                            name: product.item.name,
                            unit_amount: product.item.amount,
                            measurement: product.item.fk_unit_measurement?.name,
                            images: product.item.images,
                            quantity: product.quantity,
                            price: product.item.price,
                            discount: (product.item.price * (product.discount / 100)),
                            subtotal,
                            item_total,
                            product_amount: product.item.amount * product.quantity,
                            updated_product_amount: product.item.amount * product.quantity,
                            updated_subtotal: subtotal,
                            tax_rate: product.item.tax
                                ? product.item.tax.tax_rate
                                : farmer.fk_global_tax
                                    ? farmer.fk_global_tax.tax_rate
                                    : 0,
                            is_refunded: false
                        }
                    )
                }),
                fk_order_status: {
                    id: 1
                },
                fk_shipping_address: {
                    id: userProfile.fk_shipping_address.id
                },
                fk_billing_address: {
                    id: userProfile.fk_shipping_address.id
                }
            }

            getAxiosInstance(store).post(`/items/orders?fields=*.*.*`, orderData)
                .then((response) => {
                    const orderDataResponse = response.data.data;
                    const {
                        fk_order_items,
                        farmer,
                        restaurant,
                        id,
                        delivery_date
                    } = orderDataResponse;

                    sendPushNotification( {
                        to: userProfile.push_notification_key,
                        title: `Bestellung #${id} wurde erstellt`,
                        body: `Der Liefertermin ist: ${dayjs(delivery_date).format("DD.MM.YYYY")}`,
                        data: null,
                    })

                    // SEND TRANSACTIONAL EMAIL TO RESTAURANT
                    sendEmail({
                        templateId: "DIRECTUS_RESTAURANT_Order_Confirmation",
                        data: {
                            total: values.immediateDelivery ? subTotal : (subTotal + farmer.delivery_fee),
                            farmerFirstName: farmer.contact_first_name,
                            restaurantFirstName: restaurant.contact_first_name,
                            items: fk_order_items,
                            vendor: farmer.store_name,
                            orderNum: id,
                            delivery_fee: farmer.delivery_fee,
                            deliveryDate: dayjs(delivery_date).format("DD.MM.YYYY"),
                        },
                        recipient: restaurant.contact_email,
                    });

                    // SEND TRANSACTIONAL EMAIL TO FARMER
                    sendEmail({
                        templateId: "DIRECTUS_FARMER_New_Order_Received",
                        data: {
                            total: values.immediateDelivery ? subTotal : (subTotal + farmer.delivery_fee),
                            restaurant,
                            items: fk_order_items,
                            farmer,
                            orderNum: id,
                            delivery_fee: farmer.delivery_fee,
                            deliveryDate: dayjs(delivery_date).format("DD.MM.YYYY"),
                        },
                        recipient: farmer.contact_email,
                    });

                    // LOWER STOCK AND EMPTY CART
                    dispatch(createOrder(orderDataResponse, navigation))

                    trackAmplitudeEvent("Purchase", {
                        total: values.immediateDelivery ? subTotal : (subTotal + farmer.delivery_fee),
                        immediateDelivery: values.immediateDelivery
                    })

                    dispatch(loadingStop())
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error, "ERROR CREATING ORDER");
                    dispatch(loadingStop())
                })
        }
    }

    const handleCallback = (values) => {
        const formattedDeliveryDate = values.deliveryDate;
        formattedDeliveryDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)

        const today = new Date()
        const daysBefore = new Date(today)
        daysBefore.setDate(daysBefore.getDate() + cutoffOrderingDay)
        daysBefore.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
        //CHECK IF DELIVERY IS BEFORE CUTOFF TIME SPECIFIED BY VENDOR


        if (values.immediateDelivery) {
            Alert.alert(
                "Bist du sicher?",
                "Möchtest du direkt vor Ort (in deinem Restaurant oder auf dem Hof) bestellen?",
                [
                    {
                        text: "Ja", onPress: () => {
                            confirmSubmit(values)
                        },
                        style: "default"
                    },
                    {
                        text: "Abbrechen",
                        style: "cancel"
                    }
                ]
            )
        } else {
            confirmSubmit(values)
        }

    };
```

Comment: Does both devices have the same Screen size?
Use react-debugger‘s inspector if the button got obscured by another view.

Comment: The button is definitely pressing, as the opacity feedback is visible. It just doesn't run the "onPress" function. But the strange thing, is that it only happens this individual. I tried on both her iPhones, and still the same (even when logging into my user account). The only thing in common that those phones have is the iCloud account....

Comment: If it‘s not fire the onPress event it has nothing to ideal with iCloud or any another account.
What happen when you insert following in the onPress callback ```Àlert.alert(" I got. Executed")```

Comment: That's exactly what I implemented, and will push this to production and ask that particular client what the error outputs. Thanks for the comment